# Is it possible to mock schema fields in GaphQL request in react-query like apolloclient does it?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-query

I am working on migrating my app to react-query from apolloclient. With apolloclient, I am mocking the schema like it's shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/client-schema-mocking/). Here's what that looks like:

```
const users = [
  {
    name: "user1name",
    image: "https://user1image.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "user2name",
    image: "https://user2image.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "user3name",
    image: "https://user3image.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "user4name",
    image: "https://user4image.jpg",
  },
];

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Post: {
      fields: {
        user: {
          read() {
            return user[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Then, in the query for posts, I can just add `@client` after the user field and it will run the `read` function specified above and return the value for that field while the other fields will have the data from the backend.

I haven't been able to find any information on how to do something similar with react-query. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-query is not a graphql specific library, so any schema related things cannot be handled by it. react-query basically wants a resolved or rejected Promise returned from the `queryFn` - that's it.

So maybe this question is more related to the library that you actually use the make the graphql request, like [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request) or maybe [urql-core](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/core/)?

What you can always do is amend the data inside the `queryFn` after it was fetched, but before it was returned from `useQuery`. If you take a look at the [graphql basic example from the docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/basic-graphql-request), you could do:

```
useQuery("posts", async () => {
  const {
    posts: { data },
  } = await request(
    endpoint,
      gql`
        query {
          posts {
            data {
              id
              title
            }
          }
        }
      `
  );

  return {
    ...data,
    someOtherField: myMockedOtherFieldData };
  }
});
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using ```graphql-request```, but it doesn't seem like it can do what I want either way. Anyhow, your code is sufficient for my use case, thanks.